# Display Result from two tables sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, display

I have 2 tables, called `post` and `pcgames` 
`if $_GET['game']; is =action` 
it will seach action on table post and pcgames from column category.

**post** table

```
id|category  |game
------------------
1 | action   |cabal
------------------
2 | strategy |blackdessert
------------------
3 | RPG      |MUlegend
------------------
4 | action   |ragnarok
------------------
```

**pcgames** table

```
id|category  |game
-------------------
1 | action   |solidsnake
-------------------
2 | action   |finalfantasy
-------------------
3 | RPG      |kingdomhearts
-----------------
4 | action   |tekken
-------------------
```

**result**

```
no|category  |game
------------------
1 | action   |cabal
------------------
2 | action   |solidsnake
-------------------
3 | action   |finalfantasy
-------------------
4 | action   |tekken
-------------------
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
    $game = $_GET['game'];
    $ids = mysqli_real_escape_string($conDB,$id);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `game` ='" . $game . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conDB,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?> 
        <li> <a href="./post_list.html"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a> </li>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: what is the question/problem?

Comment: seeing `<a href="./post_list.html"><?php echo $row['title']; ?>` have you instructed your server to treat `.html` files as php? do you even have a webserver/php installed?

Comment: I'm not going to wait all night. We're not in the same timezone you and I. Unless we are and it's near midnight; so I'm on my way out too. You can stay up, not me. Good luck.

Comment: sorry i did not edit the link, i just want to get the <?php echo $row['title']; ?> from table pcgames and post that has a data "action".

Comment: you need to tell what is the problem, and second what is the value of `$conDB` turn on or the error reporting and use error messaging if you are just erroor testing by adding die or mysqli_error

Comment: and also if you are using get method atleast tell the url as well, so the people will know you are getting the value for variable

Comment: @user2860957 my problem was i don't know what query should i use to get the value of action from two tables and display there title.

http://gpad.dx.am/post.php?id=4&game=action

Comment: ok means you want to search the value for action in two tables??? in one go is that corrrect

Comment: yes search action in two table and display the result. @user2860957

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168906/data-from-two-tables-with-same-column-names read this link

Comment: @user2860957 yes i do research but my problem was im not good in php and i got error if tried to edit and copy those post. ill try my luck and post the error here

Comment: @user2860957

 <?php

$game = $_GET['game'];
$ids = mysqli_real_escape_string($conDB,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM post, pcgames WHERE category = '$game'";
$result = mysqli_query($conDB,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?> 
                  <li> <a href="#"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a> </li>
                  
                   <?php
}; 
?>

i got error it doesn't display.

Comment: first change this line `$result = mysqli_query($conDB,$query)` to this line `$result = mysqli_query($conDB,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conDB));` basically addd die , and again where is $conDB variable in your php code

Comment: and one more thing, i also dont want to waste your time as i am not expert if you don't get answer let's say in ten minutes, post this same question again, and leave link for this question, it may help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you means is get the data from table post and pcgames with category conditions. if you want to do this. try this on your php:

```
<?php
    $game = $_GET['game'];
    $ids = mysqli_real_escape_string($conDB,$id);
    $no = 1;

    //this will be get data from post table
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `category` ='" . $game . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conDB,$query); 

    //this will be get data from pcgames table
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `pcgames` WHERE `category` ='" . $game . "'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conDB,$query1);       
?>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th> <th>Category</th> <th>Game</th>
    </tr>
    <?php  
    //fetch data from post table
    while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
        echo "<td>".$no++."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$user_data['category']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$user_data['game']."</td>";     
    }
    //fetch data from pcgames table
    while($user_data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {         
        echo "<td>".$no++."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$user_data1['category']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$user_data1['game']."</td>";     
    }
    ?>
</table>
```